# Summarise? Count occurences in column based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I believe this may have a simple solution but I'm having trouble describing what I need to do (and hence what to search for). I think I need the `summarize` function. My goal output is at the very bottom.

I'm trying to count the occurrences of a value between each unique value in another column. Here is an example `df` that hopefully illustrates what I need todo.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- tibble("name" = c(rep("dinah",2),rep("lucy",4),rep("sora",9)),
             "meal" = c(rep(c("chicken","beef","fish"),5)),
             "date" = seq(as.Date("1999/1/1"),as.Date("2000/1/1"),25),
             "num.wins" = sample(0:30)[1:15])
```

Among other things, I'm trying to summarize (sum) the types of meals each name had using this data.

```
df
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   name  meal    date       num.wins
   <chr> <chr>   <date>        <int>
 1 dinah chicken 1999-01-01        8
 2 dinah beef    1999-01-26       11
 3 lucy  fish    1999-02-20       16
 4 lucy  chicken 1999-03-17       25
 5 lucy  beef    1999-04-11        5
 6 lucy  fish    1999-05-06       23
 7 sora  chicken 1999-05-31       27
 8 sora  beef    1999-06-25       15
 9 sora  fish    1999-07-20       14
10 sora  chicken 1999-08-14        1
11 sora  beef    1999-09-08        4
12 sora  fish    1999-10-03        3
13 sora  chicken 1999-10-28       13
14 sora  beef    1999-11-22        6
15 sora  fish    1999-12-17       18
```

I've made progress with other calculations I'm interested in, below:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(count=n(),
            medianDate=median(date),
            life=(max(date)-min(date)),
            wins=sum(num.wins))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  count medianDate life      wins
  <chr> <int> <date>     <time>   <int>
1 dinah     2 1999-01-13  25 days    19
2 lucy      4 1999-03-29  75 days    69
3 sora      9 1999-09-08 200 days   101
```

My goal is to add an additional column for each type of food, and have the sum of the occurrences of that food displayed in each row, like so:

```
  name  count medianDate life      wins  chicken  beef  fish
1 dinah     2 1999-01-13  25 days    19        1     1     0
2 lucy      4 1999-03-29  75 days    69        1     1     2
3 sora      9 1999-09-08 200 days   101        3     3     3
```

Comment: I guess you can use `spread` from the tidyr package and merge/join with your summarized table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though older, and possibly on a deprecation path, `reshape2::dcast` does this nicely:

```
reshape2::dcast(df, name ~ meal)
#    name beef chicken fish
# 1 dinah    1       1    0
# 2  lucy    1       1    2
# 3  sora    3       3    3
```

You can understand the formula as `rows ~ columns`. By default, it will aggregate the values in the columns using the `length` function---which gives exactly what you want, the count of each.

This can be easily joined to your summary data:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(count=n(),
            medianDate=median(date),
            life=(max(date)-min(date)),
            wins=sum(num.wins)) %>%
  left_join(reshape2::dcast(df, name ~ meal))
# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#   name  count medianDate life      wins  beef chicken  fish
#   <chr> <int> <date>     <time>   <int> <int>   <int> <int>
# 1 dinah     2 1999-01-13  25 days    19     1       1     0
# 2 lucy      4 1999-03-29  75 days    69     1       1     2
# 3 sora      9 1999-09-08 200 days   101     3       3     3
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use `table` inside `summarise` as a `list` column, `unnest` and then `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(count=n(),
             medianDate=median(date),
             life=(max(date)-min(date)),
             wins=sum(num.wins),
             n = list(enframe(table(meal))) ) %>%
  unnest %>%
  spread(name1, value, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 8
#  name  count medianDate life      wins  beef chicken  fish
#  <chr> <int> <date>     <time>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 dinah     2 1999-01-13  25 days    19     1       1     0
#2 lucy      4 1999-03-29  75 days    69     1       1     2
#3 sora      9 1999-09-08 200 days   101     3       3     3
```

Comment: This is also great, had i not used the checked answer I would have used this one. thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting the funky formatting for `life`, but I think this gets at your need for a count of the meal types.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(count=n(),
            medianDate=median(date),
            life=(max(date)-min(date)),
            wins=sum(num.wins),
            chicken = sum(meal == "chicken"),
            beef = sum(meal == "beef"),
            fish = sum(meal == "fish"))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
  name  count medianDate life        wins chicken  beef  fish
  <chr> <int> <date>     <time>     <int>   <int> <int> <int>
1 dinah     2 1999-01-13 " 25 days"    19       1     1     0
2 lucy      4 1999-03-29 " 75 days"    69       1     1     2
3 sora      9 1999-09-08 200 days     101       3     3     3
```

Comment: thanks this answer is useful and much simpler than i thought it would be. i checked gregors answer as in my case I have many "foods" and his method doesn't require me to manually list them out. thanks again